# Simulate authentication or login when using Behat + Symfony

Tags: bdd, symfony, behat, mink

Most part of my app requires that the `User` is logged in and some parts requires the `User` has specific role.

I have this feature file.

```
  Background:
        Given I am logged in as "saif"
        And I am making transaction for "Jaime Sangcap"


    @critical @javascript
    Scenario: Transaction having a sales person for commission
        Given there is "General English Level 1" which costs "499" on the product list
        When I add the "General English Level 1"
        And I assign "Emy Ventura" as the sales person
        Then I should see "Emy Ventura" as the sales person
```

And here is my Context file.

```
<?php


namespace Akademia\Institution\Behat\Sales\Context;


use Akademia\Institution\Behat\Common\Context\CanAuthenticateWithKernel;
use Akademia\Institution\Sales\Domain\Model\Client;
use Akademia\Institution\Sales\Domain\Model\ClientRepository;
use Behat\Behat\Tester\Exception\PendingException;
use Behat\Behat\Context\SnippetAcceptingContext;
use Behat\Mink\Driver\BrowserKitDriver;
use Behat\Mink\Exception\UnsupportedDriverActionException;
use Behat\MinkExtension\Context\MinkContext;
use Behat\Symfony2Extension\Context\KernelAwareContext;
use Behat\Symfony2Extension\Context\KernelDictionary;
use Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\Purger\ORMPurger;
use Symfony\Component\BrowserKit\Cookie;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\UsernamePasswordToken;

class SalesUiContext extends MinkContext implements SnippetAcceptingContext, KernelAwareContext
{
    use KernelDictionary;

    /** @var ClientRepository */
    private $clientRepository;
    private $clientName;

    /**
     * @BeforeScenario
     */
    public function clearData()
    {
        $em = $this->getContainer()->get('doctrine.orm.sales_entity_manager');
        $em->getConnection()->executeQuery('SET foreign_key_checks = 0;');
        $purger = new ORMPurger($em);
        $purger->purge();
    }

    /**
     * @BeforeScenario
     */
    public function loadFixtures()
    {
        shell_exec('bin/console hautelook_alice:doctrine:fixtures:load -n --env=test');
    }

    /**
     * @Given I am making transaction for :name
     */
    public function iAmMakingTransactionFor($name)
    {
        $this->clientName = $name;
        $this->clientRepository = $this->getContainer()->get('akademia_institution.sales.client_repository');
        $this->clientRepository->add(Client::withMinimumDetails($name, '056xxxxxxx', 'irrelevant source'));
        $this->visit(sprintf('clients/?keyword=%s', $name));
        $this->clickLink('register');
    }

    /**
     * @Given there is :arg1 which costs :arg2 on the product list
     */
    public function thereIsWhichCostsOnTheProductList($arg1, $arg2)
    {
        throw new PendingException();
    }

    /**
     * @When I add the :arg1
     */
    public function iAddThe($arg1)
    {
        throw new PendingException();
    }

    /**
     * @When I assign :arg1 as the sales person
     */
    public function iAssignAsTheSalesPerson($arg1)
    {
        throw new PendingException();
    }

    /**
     * @Then I should see :arg1 as the sales person
     */
    public function iShouldSeeAsTheSalesPerson($arg1)
    {
        throw new PendingException();
    }

    /**
     * @Given I am logged in as :username
     * @Given I am logged in
     */
    public function iAmLoggedInAs($username = null)
    {
        $driver = $this->getSession('symfony_session')->getDriver();
        if (! ($driver instanceof BrowserKitDriver)) {
            throw new UnsupportedDriverActionException('This step is only supported by the BrowserKitDriver', $driver);
        }

        $client = $driver->getClient();
        $client->getCookieJar()->set(new Cookie(session_name(), true));

        $session = $client->getContainer()->get('session');

        $firewall = $this->getContainer()->getParameter('fos_user.firewall_name');
        $user = $this->getContainer()->get('elite.user_repository')->findByUser($username);
        $token = new UsernamePasswordToken($user, null, $firewall, $user->getRoles());
        $session->set('_security_'.$firewall, serialize($token));
        $session->save();

        $cookie = new Cookie($session->getName(), $session->getId());
        $client->getCookieJar()->set($cookie);
    }
}
```

behat.yml file

```
default:
    gherkin:
        filters:
            tags: "~@wip&&~@disabled"

    extensions:
            Behat\Symfony2Extension:
                kernel:
                    env: test
            Behat\MinkExtension:
                base_url: http://elitesolutions.app
                javascript_session: selenium2_session
                default_session: goutte_session
                sessions:
                    goutte_session:
                        goutte: ~
                    symfony_session:
                        symfony2: ~
                    selenium2_session:
                        selenium2:
                            wd_host: http://192.168.100.0/wd/hub
                            capabilities:
                                browser: firefox
                                version: ANY
    suites:


        sales:
            paths: [ "%paths.base%/features/Sales" ]
            contexts: [ Akademia\Institution\Behat\Sales\Context\SalesDomainContext ]

        sales_ui:
            paths: ["%paths.base%/features/Sales"]
            contexts: [ Akademia\Institution\Behat\Sales\Context\SalesUiContext ]
            filters:
                tags: "@critical"
```

The `Given I am logged in as "saif"` is passing
But Im having error on the next step 
`And I am making transaction for "Jaime Sangcap"` saying:

```
Link with id|title|alt|text "register" not found. (Behat\Mink\Exception\ElementNotFoundException)
```

Which I think is because when trying to visit the url, its being redirected to the login page and not on the intended url (page).

bacause most of my scenarios requires you're logged in I dont like to authenticate them on the real login form on every scenario.

Is there a way to do that, like manually setting the Token?

I've tried following this [post](https://medium.com/@robinvdvleuten/handle-authenticated-users-in-behat-mink-cfca29596d94#.uu6jl9zdm) but couldn't get it to work

**EDIT:**

I think the problem is Im using two database, the symfony2 session is using the `test` environment which points to `elite_solutions_test` while the selenium2 is using `dev` environment which points to `elite_solutions_dev`

here is my behat.yml

```
extensions:
        Behat\Symfony2Extension:
            kernel:
                env: test
        Behat\MinkExtension:
            base_url: http://elitesolutions.app
            default_session: symfony
            javascript_session: javascript
            browser_name: phantomjs
            sessions:
                goutte:
                    goutte: ~
                symfony:
                    symfony2: ~
                javascript:
                    selenium2:
                        wd_host: http://10.0.2.2:4444/wd/hub
```

parameters.yml

```
# This file is auto-generated during the composer install
parameters:
    database_host: 127.0.0.1
    database_port: 3306
    database_name: elite_solutions_dev
    database_user: homestead
    database_password: secret
    mailer_transport: smtp
    mailer_host: 127.0.0.1
    mailer_user: null
    mailer_password: null
    secret: ThisTokenIsNotSoSecretChangeIt
```

config_test.yml

```
imports:
    - { resource: config_dev.yml }

framework:
    test: ~
    session:
        storage_id: session.storage.mock_file
    profiler:
        collect: false

web_profiler:
    toolbar: false
    intercept_redirects: false

swiftmailer:
    disable_delivery: true

doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver:   pdo_mysql
        host:     "%database_host%"
        port:     "%database_port%"
        dbname:   elite_solutions_test
        user:     "%database_user%"
        password: "%database_password%"
        charset:  UTF8

#security:
#    firewalls:
#        main:
#            http_basic: ~

hautelook_alice:
    db_drivers:
        orm: true
    locale: en_US       # Locale to used for faker; must be a valid Faker locale otherwise will fallback to en_EN
    seed: 1             # A seed to make sure faker generates data consistently across runs, set to null to disable
    persist_once: false # Only persist objects once if multiple files are passed
    loading_limit: 5    # Maximum number of time the loader will try to load the files passed
```

How should I tell the selenium2 to use the test environment? or should I add app_test.php?

Comment: How do you know the login step is passing? do you check somehow that is logged in?Have you tried to print the current url before giving this error?

Comment: Hmm interesting, I don't check if its logged in :) missed that one, good catch. I did test before that the page contains login thats why I know its being redirected. But I think the problem is with javascript tag placed on the scenario because its using symfony2 session and selenium session, removing the javascript tag makes it passed. Any idea how to solve it without removing the javascript tag or should I say using selenium2 session?

Comment: Usually you should also use @insulated tag for the scenario, add this tag and see what happens.

Comment: Its throwing exception that its not instance of BrowserKit driver. Behat\Mink\Driver\Selenium2Driver is the class being returned here `$driver = $this->getSession('symfony_session')->getDriver();` which is true. But I think the common interface that I should follow should be `Behat\Mink\Driver\DriverInterface` but it does not have the `getClient()` which is being used on the link I've provided.

Comment: Could it be an issue that you are using multiple sessions? and when you are doing the login you are using symfony_session and maybe you are continuing  with different session. Take a quick look here http://mink.behat.org/en/latest/guides/managing-sessions.html

Comment: Thanks for the link, appreciate it. I'll try to review and get back soon

Comment: I think the problem is Im using two database, the symfony2 session is using the `test` environment which points to `elite_solutions_test` while the selenium2 is using `dev` environment which points to `elite_solutions_dev`